# cant reset password in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter with Firebase, I am signing in using the email and it works fine, but I can't send a password reset email to it.

```
forgotMyPassword(String email)async {
    try {
      await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email.trim());
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);  
    }
}
```

it always gives me back this message and code

> W/System  (25110): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value
> was null. I/flutter (25110): invalid-email I/flutter (25110): The
> email address is badly formatted.

Comment: are you sure that you are passing the correct email as an argument?

Comment: the answer to your question is written in the error. Apparently the Email you are providing does not have the right format. Maybe spaces or other characters between/in the email? Try to check it

Comment: I am positive that I write the right address, I take it by copying it from the firebase

Comment: In that case you should be able to reproduce the problem with hard-coded value too. So: initialize `email` with a hard-coded string in your code, and reproduce it with that. If you can do that, edit your question to show the updated code.

Comment: while I was trying your suggestion, it turns out I had a bug with a null value along the way.
thank you for your help